# Pandas read_csv index exception

Tags: python, csv, pandas, import-from-csv

I am using the pandas function `read_csv` to read a CSV with no index column.

```
read_csv("file.csv", header=1)
```

I was expecting that PANDAS would generate an index for each row based on the [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/io.html#csv-text-files)

> index_col: column number, column name, or list of column numbers/names, to use as the index (row labels) of the resulting DataFrame. By default, it will number the rows without using any column, unless there is one more data column than there are headers, in which case the first column is taken as the index.

However, while loading the file it throws,

```
Exception: Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

And I cannot figure out why this would be the case.  What causes this exception?

I have also tried passing `skiprows` and `nrows` and the same exception occurs.

Comment: Can you give an example of the data?

Comment: it's all over the place.  strings, ints, floats, dates.  But I am not trying to parse any of it to a particular data type.

Comment: I mean you need to give a specific example.  Like, provide a sample data file that actually causes the error.  The problem almost certainly has to do with the specifics of how that file is formatted and what data it contains.

Comment: Sorry @BrenBarn I didn't feel comfortable posting my data.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the `header` argument is not a `True`/`False` type argument.  Rather, it specifies the row number for the header.  Since it is specified as `1` it is using the 2nd row for the header and considering that this row contains actual data, the values are not necissarily unique.

Changing the command to

```
read_csv("file.csv")
```

or

```
read_csv("file.csv", header=0)
```

fixes the problem.  It is such a "duh" moment but being used to R I mistakenly thought `header=1` was specifying to read a header.  Ugh.

For future reference, the Exception

```
Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects
```

relates to the header values not being unique.

Comment: What version of pandas are you using? `read_csv` seemed to work ok on a few toy examples I came up with using non-unique headers. I don't know if you can come up with a specific data set that reproduces the issue without divulging data you want to keep private.